# Haskell: Need Enlightenment with Calculator program

Tags: haskell, calculator

I have an assignment which is to create a calculator program in Haskell. For example, users will be able to use the calculator by command lines like:

```
>var cola =5; //define a random variable
>cola*2+1;
(print 11)
>var pepsi = 10 
>coca > pepsi;
(print false)
>def coke(x,y) = x+y;  //define a random function
>coke(cola,pepsi);
(print 15)
```

//and actually it's more complicated than above

I have no clue how to program this in Haskell. All I can think of right now is to read the command line as a String, parse it into an array of tokens. Maybe go through the array, detect keywords such "var", "def" then call functions var, def which store variables/functions in a List or something like that. But then how do I store data so that I can use them later in my computation?

Also am I on the right track because I am actually very confused what to do next? :(

****In addition, I am not allowed to use Parsec***!*

Comment: you can use [`lex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:lex), right?

Comment: Write your own tiny parser combinator library! It's gonna be fun and you will learn a lot about monads and applicative functors :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have two distinct kinds of input: declarations (creating new variables and functions) and expressions (calculating things).

You should first define some data structures so you can work out what sort of things you are going to be dealing with. Something like:

```
data Command = Define Definition | Calculate Expression | Quit
type Name = String
data Definition = DefVar Name Expression | DefFunc Name [Name] Expression
-- ^ alternatively, implement variables as zero-argument functions
-- and merge these cases
data Expression = Var Name | Add Expression Expression | -- ... other stuff
type Environment = [Definition]
```

To start off with, just parse (tokenise and then parse the tokens, perhaps) the stuff into a `Command`, and then decide what to do with it.

Expressions are comparatively easy. You assume you already have all the definitions you need (an `Environment`) and then just look up any variables or do additions or whatever.

Definitions are a bit trickier. Once you've decided what new definition to make, you need to add it to the environment. How exactly you do this depends on how exactly you iterate through the lines, but you'll need to pass the new environment back from the interpreter to the thing which fetches the next line and runs the interpreter on it. Something like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = mainLoop emptyEnv
 where
  emptyEnv = []

mainLoop :: Environment -> IO ()
mainLoop env = do
  str <- getLine
  case parseCommnad str of
    Nothing -> do
      putStrLn "parse failed!"
      mainLoop env
    Just Quit -> do
      return ()
    Just (Define d) -> do
      mainLoop (d : env)
    Just (Calculate e) -> do
      putStrLn (calc env e)
      mainLoop env

-- the real meat:
parseCommand :: String -> Maybe Command
calc :: Environment -> Expression -> String -- or Integer or some other appropriate type
```

`calc` will need to look stuff up in the environment you create as you go along, so you'll probably also need a function for finding which `Definition` corresponds to a given `Name` (or complaining that there isn't one).

Some other decisions you should make:

- What do I do when someone tries to redefine a variable?
- What if I used one of those variables in the definition of a function? Do I evaluate a function definition when it is created or when it is used?

These questions may affect the design of the above program, but I'll leave it up to you to work out how.

Comment: Thanks, I will need to handle the case when users redefine the variable. Can you explain further about the use of data and type? I think when a variable/function is declared, I will need to store it's nam, parameters and expression. Therefore I declare a new type:
 type VariableDef Name [Parameter] Value = (Name,[Parameter],Value) 
The question is when I use "type" and when I use "data"? And do I need definition for each type (i.e Parameter, Value etc) because they are new?

Comment: The syntax you gave for `type` is wrong: you don't need your type synonym to have parameters, just `type VariableDef = (Name, [Parameter], Value)` would be fine. When to use `type` or `data` – in this case it doesn't matter so much, but I tend to prefer `data`. All `type` does is create a synonym for some tuple type. You could pass in tuples that weren't variable definitions and it could typecheck fine. Defining a new data type ensures that this can't happen. I don't understand your last question. Obviously you can't use types you haven't defined.

Comment: Oh I meant for example:
data Definition = DefVar Name Expression | DefFunc Name [Name] Expression.
Do we need to define DefVar, DefFunc, Name, Expression?

Comment: The form of a data declaration is `data TypeName = ConstructorName ParameterType1 ParameterType2 ... | OtherConstructor MoreTypes ...`. The arguments to your constructors have to be types that are declared elsewhere, but the constructors themselves are *created* by the `data` declaration. So `DefVar` and `DefFunc` don't need to already exist.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can learn a lot from this [tutorial for haskell programming](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters)

You need to write your function in another doc with .hs
And you can load the file from you compiler and use all the function you create
For example

```
plus :: Int -> Int  -- that mean the function just work with a number of type int and return Int
plus x y = x + y    -- they receive x and y and do the operation
```

Comment: Hi, I know basics of Haskell because this is the assignment in my Intro to Haskell course. Actually is it more complicated than just write a function to do computation on two numbers. The users will perform any kind of computations on as many variables as he wants. What if he wants to compute a+b/c*d-e? Moreover, users need to be able to store numbers in variables, not just feed direct numbers to the program (as the example I gave above).

Comment: +1 on content. I like your posts. You have much to contribute. Take a little more time to think about how to apply your insight. try to guess less and solve more. takes real investment, but I hope you stick with it. chag semeyach.

Comment: I wish I could, the problem is time constrain, I have barely 1 week to complete this assignment. Furthermore, writing programs in Haskell for me is equivalent to writing essays in alien languages. I need to learn all the new grammars and vocabs :(

Comment: if anyone need help for all the function a good part is based on lisp function. and lisp have more information